# Checkstyle, how to enforce the presence of a serialisation ID?

Tags: java, continuous-integration, checkstyle

does anyone know of a Checkstyle Check
to enforce the presence of a serialisation ID in any class that implements Serializable.

For example:

```
public class Accounts extends implements Serializable {
```

Should be forced to have the field

```
/**
* Id for serialization
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

There does not seem to be a check for this specific case

and I was unclear how to use / ,if it was appropriate to use, the "Regexp" check for this case, 
as I was not sure how to apply this to specific classes (the ones that implements Serializable)?

any pointers or help would be fantastic. 
Thanks all. 
luke

Comment: I'm not familiar with checkstyle, but a missing `serialVersionUID` generates a compiler warning, so I'd imagine it's easy to check for.

Comment: Since I see serialVersionUID's added left and right for no reason, I must ask: do you ever plan to read old serialized data in a newer version of your application and expect it to work?  If the answer is no, don't bother with serialVersionUID's.

Comment: @shmosel this is true however enforcing a coding standard in a large team is difficult and people ignore warnings . unfortunately. :)

Comment: @john16384 true, but yes it is needed :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible with Checkstyle out of the box. (For various reasons, one of them being that since Checkstyle operates on source code instead of byte code, it is not so easy to tell whether a class implements `Serializable`.) However, you could [write a custom check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html) to do it.

Having said that, you may want to try [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), if that is possible for you. It has a check called [SE_NO_SERIALVERSIONID](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SE_NO_SERIALVERSIONID) which should do just what you need. And some more related checks, too, such as [SE_NONFINAL_SERIALVERSIONID](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SE_NONFINAL_SERIALVERSIONID), [SE_NONLONG_SERIALVERSIONID](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SE_NONLONG_SERIALVERSIONID), or [SE_NONSTATIC_SERIALVERSIONID](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SE_NONSTATIC_SERIALVERSIONID).